# TextView Alignment in LinearLayout android. Unable to place it at Center of Layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, center

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Team A"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <!-- unable to place this 3 TextViews at center position of layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- make this as center -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="00"
            android:textSize="70sp" />

        <!-- make this as center -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="/"
            android:textSize="70sp" />

        <!-- make this as center -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="70sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try this android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Comment: Unbale to add this tag.As it is an LinearLayout. centerHorizontal is displaying as an invalid attribute

Comment: add `android:gravity="center"` to your inner linear layout, that makes it all

Comment: @Yogesh ...what was wrong with my answer???

Comment: nothing its working fine . Sorry I saw your code now.

Comment: @HamidShatu lolzz... is it an election to get to vote up from the voters and if they don't vote up your answer, ask them that why they didn't do that :P

Comment: @Devraj...its not the matter of up vote...its a matter of accepting correct answer and the timing of correct answer given earlier than others. So, the correct answer has been given first should be accepted not the latter. I think you got your lolzz's answer. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:gravity=""` attribute to the parent `LinearLayout` of those 3 `TextViews` with value of `center_horizontal`. Those `TextViews` will be centered.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

   <TextView ... />

   <TextView ... />

    <TextView ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" in textViews
```

Answer (score 0):

you should set linearLayout fill parent and set Gravity for linearLayout. try this:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="00"
        android:textSize="70sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/" >
    </TextView>
         android:textSize="70sp"
        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        as=""
        center=""
        make=""
        this=""
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="70sp" />
```

Comment: cant set  android:layout_height="fill_parent" because I am using few more views below this one.Tried width as fill parent still not working

Answer (score 0):

Make parent layout a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`, and then in you child `LinearLayout` which has the `TextViews` you want in center add these properties

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
```

or

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="00"
            android:textSize="70sp" />

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="/"                     
            android:textSize="70sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"                       
            android:textSize="70sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Resultant image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following xml. 
in this xml using the advantages of the   `android:weightSum` property

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="frrdt" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:weightSum="1.5">

       <View android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight=".3"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="desra"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
          />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" dersa"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
               android:gravity="center"/>
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" dersa"
          android:layout_weight=".3"
               android:gravity="center" />
          <View android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight=".3"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like specific control of location of xml widgets within your layout then I recommend using a RelativeLayout. Then you can use:

android:layout_below="@+id/yourTextviewId"

etc. to place widgets with respect to each other and you can use:

android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

etc. to align them with respect to the layout. 
Hope this helps!